# Getting variables of an XML document root node in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I have an XML file in R. The XML file looks like this:

```
<pdv id="1000001" latitude="4620114" longitude="519791" cp="01000" pop="R">
  <adresse>ROUTE NATIONALE</adresse>
  <ville>SAINT-DENIS-LÃ¨S-BOURG</ville>
  <ouverture debut="01:00" fin="01:00" saufjour=""/>
  <services>
    <service>Automate CB</service>
    <service>Vente de gaz domestique</service>
    <service>Station de gonflage</service>
  </services>
  <prix nom="Gazole" id="1" maj="2014-01-02 11:08:03" valeur="1304"/>
  <prix nom="SP98" id="6" maj="2014-12-31 08:39:46" valeur="1285"/>
  [....]
  <fermeture/>
  <rupture/>
</pdv>
```

I want to subtract the information about id="1000001" and  latitude="4620114" (the first line of the XML file) and put it in a matrix.

But when I run the:

```
rootNode[[1]]
```

I get the second line of the XML file: ROUTE NATIONALE

What do I have to do to get the first line (latitude, longitude and id information) and put it a matrix?

Comment: how you've created `rootNode` object?

Comment: I used rootNode <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to extract attribute of element.
Check function xpathApply for this purposes

Smth like following.

```
# Using xpathApply, we can do
latitude = xpathApply(doc, "/pdv", xmlGetAttr, "latitude", namespaces = namespaces )
latitude = unlist(latitude)
# Using an expression rather than a function and ...
latitude = xpathApply(doc, "/pdv",
quote(xmlGetAttr(x, "latitude")), namespaces = namespaces )
```

[Documentation on work with xml .](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/XML.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, but I having this error: Error in is(namespaces, "list") : object 'namespaces' not found